# How to play video in viewflipper

Tags: android

I have  a viewflipper in which there are videos and images.Everything works fine when it run for first time.After the last child is shown and the view are repeated,in that case videos are not playing and a black screen remain all the time.
Thanks in advance.

My code

```
    @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kiosk_mode);
        mSelectedPressoId=PreferenceConnector.readString(KioskModeActivity.this,         PreferenceConnector.SELECTED_PRESSO_ID, "");
        bindControl();
        fetchSlidesFromDb();
    }
public void bindControl(){
    mFlipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    mParentView=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_background);
    mKioskModeIcon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.kiosk_mode_icon);
    mExitBar=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.exit_bar);
    detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    mCounter=new MyCounter(10000, 1000);
    mActivePointers = new SparseArray<PointF>();
    mKioskModeIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mHomeIcon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.homeIcon); 
    mHomeIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCommonMethod=new CommonMethod(getApplicationContext());
    position=new ArrayList<String>();
    mTransitionTime=PreferenceConnector.readString(getApplicationContext(), PreferenceConnector.TRANSITION_TIME, "");
    Log.v("transition time from prefrence isss",mTransitionTime+">>>");

    if(mTransitionTime.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
    mFlipper.setFlipInterval(10000);
    }else{
        int mTransitionTimeInMills=Integer.parseInt(mTransitionTime)*1000; 
        mFlipper.setFlipInterval(mTransitionTimeInMills);
    }

    mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_left_out));

    mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(    
            getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_left_in));

    mFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
          public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
          public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

              Log.d("new view is ",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
          }
          public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

              mVideoPosition=mFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
              Log.d("new view is flipped",mVideoPosition+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+mPressoPathList.get(mVideoPosition));
              if(mSlideTypeList.get(mVideoPosition).equalsIgnoreCase("video")){
                  Log.d("onside iffffff",myVideoView+">>>>>");
                  myVideoView.start();
              }
          }
       });
    mFlipper.startFlipping();

    mFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              detector.onTouchEvent(event);   
             return true;
        }
    });
}
public void fetchSlidesFromDb(){
    PresentationDatabase databaseClass = new PresentationDatabase(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.DATABASE_NAME, null, DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.DATABASE_VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseClass.getReadableDatabase();
    mPressoPathList=new ArrayList<String>();
    mSlideTypeList=new ArrayList<String>();

    String where = DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.PRESENTATION_ID + "="
            +"'"+mSelectedPressoId+"'";
    Cursor mCursor=db.query(DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.TABLE_NAME, null, where,
            null, null, null, null);
    Log.e("cursor size isssssss",mCursor.getCount()+">>");
    if(mCursor.getCount()>0){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            String slide_content_path=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.CONTENT_LOCAL_PATH));
            String mSlideType=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtil.PresenationTable.SLIDE_TYPE));
            if(!mSlideType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")){
               mPressoPathList.add(slide_content_path);
               mSlideTypeList.add(mSlideType);
            }
        }while(mCursor.moveToNext());


         }

     Log.d("slide path issssssss",mPressoPathList+"");
     setFlipperImage(mSlideTypeList, mPressoPathList);
     mCursor.close();
     db.close();

}
//create view to be put in view flipper
private void setFlipperImage(ArrayList<String>mSlideType,ArrayList<String>mSlidePath) {

    int size=mSlideType.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(mSlideType.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

            ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSlidePath.get(i),options);
            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            image.setTag(i);
            position.add(i+"");
            mFlipper.addView(image);

    }else{
         myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
         myVideoView.setVideoPath(mSlidePath.get(i));
         Log.e("my video path isssss",mSlidePath.get(i));
         myVideoView.requestFocus();
         myVideoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        // l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
         myVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
         mFlipper.addView(myVideoView);
         myVideoView.start();
         myVideoView.seekTo(500);


         myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
             @Override
             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 mFlipper.stopFlipping();
             }
         });
         myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {   

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("inside oncomplete listner",">>>>>");
                myVideoView.stopPlayback();
                mVideoPosition=mVideoPosition+1;
                mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(mVideoPosition);
                mFlipper.startFlipping();
                myVideoView.seekTo(500);

            }
        });
    }

    //
}

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //do nothing*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding

```
myVideoView.start();
```

into the Event Listener

```
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             mFlipper.stopFlipping();
             myVideoView.start();
     }
});
```